# No return from curl when requesting video annotation

Tags: video-intelligence-api

Hi, I'm following the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/getting-started#make_an_annotate_video_request) to request an video annotation processing.

```
curl -s -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN_PASTED_HERE' 'https://videointelligence.googleapis.com/v1/videos:annotate' -d @request.json
```

My json file includes the public link to the video file stored in the project bucket.

```
    {
   "inputUri":"https://storage.googleapis.com/PROJECT_URL_HERE/video.mp4",
   "features": [
       "LABEL_DETECTION"
    ]
    }
```

I'm supposed to get a response with the operation name:

> The Video Intelligence API creates an operation to process your
>   request. The response includes the operation name:
>
> {   "name": "us-west1.18358601230245040268" }

The actual result I get is nothing, not even an error. Just a moment of waiting followed by a blank command line.

My dashboard shows a successful creation of my credentials but shows no activity on the Video Intelligence API.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `inputUri` field must be a valid GCS path in the format `gs://BUCKET_NAME/path/to/video` as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/reference/rest/v1/videos/annotate#http-request), and not the `https://storage.googleapis.com` link you are using. Otherwise, it should return `google.rpc.Code.INVALID_ARGUMENT`. If you don't get any output maybe it's a syntax error (see steps below). In my case, it reads:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

If, instead, you use one of the public examples in `gs://` format in your `request.json`:

```
{
   "inputUri":"gs://cloud-ml-sandbox/video/chicago.mp4",
   "features": [
       "LABEL_DETECTION"
   ]
}
```

and then activate the service account and request the video annotations by running the following:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=/path/to/credentials.json
curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
           "https://videointelligence.googleapis.com/v1/videos:annotate" \
        -d @request.json
```

you'll get a response like:

```
{
  "name": "europe-west1.16***************80"
}
```

Once you have the operation name you can check the status with:

```
curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
    "https://videointelligence.googleapis.com/v1/operations/europe-west1.16***************80" > result.json
```

Verify that it is done with:

```
cat result.json | grep done
```

If finished, that should output:

```
"done": true,
```

and `result.json` will contain the requested annotations:

```
"annotationResults": [
  {
    "inputUri": "/cloud-ml-sandbox/video/chicago.mp4",
    "segmentLabelAnnotations": [
      {
        "entity": {
          "entityId": "/m/0pg52",
          "description": "taxi",
          "languageCode": "en-US"
        },
        ...
```